# How to bind combobox with static list of string and update the property value by selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, two-way-binding

**Update:**

I successfully enable to update property by change value in the textbox. But for the combobox I am still confused. I update the code so that might help to illustrate my confusion.

```
    class viewModelObj:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,string> generalNote { get; set; }

        private int _weight;
        public int Weight
        {
            get { return _weight; }
            set
            {
                _weight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Weight");
                MessageBox.Show($"Weight changed from model.");
            }
        }

        private string _material;
        public string Material
        {
            get { return _material; }
            set
            {
                _material = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Material");
                MessageBox.Show($"Material changed from model.");
            }
        }
        public viewModelObj(string name)
        {
            displayName = name;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="catDocListView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="16" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding viewModelSource}" DisplayMemberPath="displayName">
    </ListBox>
    <ComboBox x:Name="materialCombo" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8" ItemsSource="{Binding viewModelSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding viewModelObj}">
         <ComboBoxItem>ABC</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>DEF</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>XYZ</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" Text="{Binding ElementName=catDocListView, Path=SelectedItem.Weight, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="generalNoteDG" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding generalNoteSource}">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Note" Binding="{Binding note}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="No" Binding="{Binding no}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="English Note" Binding="{Binding eng}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="German Note" Binding="{Binding deu}" Width="Auto"/>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The viewModelSource is a ObservableCollection of viewModelObj class.

If you check the TextBox tag you will understand. Assuming I have now two items in the ListBox, I select the first one and the corresponding textbox shows the value of Weight property. I update the textbox then the value is also updated. After I select the second item and switch back to the first item, the value shown in the textbox should be the already updated one.

I want the same feature to the combobox.

**Original Post**

I try to explain the question more clearly because I think it is little tricky.

Let's say we have a `Listbox` that displays all possible items, a `Combobox` that displays available item which are independant to any other value, a `Textbox` and a `Datagrid` that shows preloaded values which are also independant to any other value, in a GUI page.

A class `viewModelObj` has some properties corresponding to the `Combobox`, `Textbox` and `Datagrid`. A `ObservableCollection` contains several such classes.

I now one-way bind the `ObservableCollection` to the `Listbox`. No matter which item I choose in the `Listbox`, the available items in the `Combobox` and values in the `Datagrid` should remain unchanged. But when I make the selection in `Combobox` and `Datagrid` (it has a checkbox column), the corresponding property of the `viewModelObj` class should be changed/added (at the beginning they are null).

XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="catDocListView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="16" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="displayName">
    </ListBox>
    <ComboBox x:Name="materialCombo" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="8" ItemsSource="{Binding viewModelSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding viewModelObj}">
         <ComboBoxItem>ABC</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>DEF</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>XYZ</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black"></TextBox>
    <DataGrid x:Name="generalNoteDG" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding generalNoteSource}">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Note" Binding="{Binding note}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="No" Binding="{Binding no}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="English Note" Binding="{Binding eng}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="German Note" Binding="{Binding deu}" Width="Auto"/>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The viewModelSource and generalNoteSource are all in the viewModel.cs

As you can see, the Datagrid source binds to another List and the availble items in the Combobox are given manuelly. When I try to bind the itemsource of the Combobox to the ObservableCollection of the viewModelObj, an error pops up.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.'
```

The viewModelObj:

```
    class viewModelObj
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string material { get; set; }
        public int weight { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,string> generalNote { get; set; }

        public viewModelObj(string name)
        {
            displayName = name;
        }
    }
```

The display property shows item in Listbox, material refers to the combobox and the generalNote corresponds to the value selected in the datagrid.

Now I'm confused how to use two-way binding to get selected values in the combobox, datagrid and textbox with predefined values.

Hope I explain the question clear.

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: you shouldn't add comboboxitems (`<ComboBoxItem>ABC</ComboBoxItem>`) since you use ItemsSource

Comment: @ASh If I don't add ComboBoxItem, should I add these predefined value in the viewModelObj class? But they are unchanged values, would that be redundant?

Answer (score 1):

You can't both bind the `ItemsSource` to a source collection and add items to the `ComboBox` in the XAML markup. It's one way or the other - not both.

You source collection should contain the values that you want to display in the `ComboBox`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> viewModelSource { get; } = new string[] { "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ" };
```

Then gid rid of the `ComboBoxItem` elements from the XAML markup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="materialCombo" ... ItemsSource="{Binding viewModelSource}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding viewModelObj}" />
```

The `viewModelObj` should store the currently selected (`string`) value in the `ComboBox`:

```
public string viewModelObj { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have tried that. It does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? The binding? Then you haven't set or implemented your `DataContext`correctly. Of course this works otherwise. It's like the first thing you learn in MVVM...

Comment: I have tried to bind the ItemsSource to the string list and bind SelectedItem to the property of the class. Then I test the GUI, the value is not updated.

Comment: You must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `viewModelObj` property if you want any UI element bound to the property to be updated. But that's another story.

Comment: I implement that later this afternoon. Now I can update the textbox and its corresponding property. But the combox still confuses me. You can check my update. Hope that I did right.

Comment: The XAML is still invalid. Read my answer again...

Comment: I set the DataContext later correctly, now it works. Thank you.